# Can't see variable values in Locals or Autos in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 version 14.0.25422.01 Update 3.
I can't see variable values in Locals or in Autos. They are just empty. 
I googled and came up with couple of suggestions:

- I've started Visual Studio in Administrator mode,
- Debug -> Options -> Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators
- Use managed compability mode

What should I do to be able to see the variables?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQr55.jpg)

Comment: You need to pause the application or hit a breakpoint to be able to see values in Auto/Local window.

Comment: Pause doesn't work for some reason but breakpoint does. Thank you.